# Should custom annotations be used to store information about an object?

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations

After searching online for the use of custom Java annotations, it's still not 100% clear to me where I should and should not be using them.

Let's say we have an abstract class called `Paperwork` that is being extended by several subclasses like `Taxes` or `Homework`. Each of these subclasses gets annotated with `@Paperwork` that includes 1 or 2 required parameters and a wide variety of parameters with a certain default value.

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Paperwork {

    String name();

    boolean important() default false;

    int dueBy() default Calendar.MONDAY;

    // more variables...
}
```

`Paperwork` now does some internal work in a method `getSummary()`. It looks for all the classes that are annotated with `@Paperwork`, and creates a general summary/overview of all paperwork. Any classes not annotated with it are still in development, and get simply ignored.

So far, this *could* have been realized by a constructor or builder pattern.

But now you want the summary itself to be treated as a type of `Paperwork` aswell, so you create a `Summary` class annotated with `@Paperwork` that now creates the summary view. The annotation processing, however, stays in the superclass. This allows the superclass to supply information about the summary to the summary itself without the need of any getters.

**Now my question is:** Is this a good use of custom annotations?
With the annotation, the superclass can fetch each classes data and store it in a single variable, instead of 20 fields for 20 possible parameters, and 20 more getters if you want to keep them private.

It just seems a bit odd to me to rely on an annotation to provide data that is only really relevant to a single subclass.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: There are few cases (dependency injection  comes to mind) where a task can't be done by using other language features. In your example, annotations are certainly not required but can help make the code more readable. They often convey the intentions of the programmer more clearly than other language' constructs and are thus often preferred.